# How to create selection button with difference function of filter date in PHP Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

Currently, I want to create a selection button with different function. The button consist of two selection which is traveled date and issued date. So when the user, click the traveled date, it will filter the traveled date function and when the user click the issued date, it will filter the issued date function. I have created the selection button in view.blade.php. and the function of the filter date. I tried to connect the right selection to the right function but it seems didn't work. How do I pass the value of the selection actually? So that, when the function get the value, they will filter the date.

[image: The image of the button]

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" name="insurance_id" onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
     <option value="Travelled" id="myInput">Travel Date</option>
     <option value="Issued" id="myButton">Issued Date</option>
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
public function filterDate(Request $request)
    {
        $insurances = Insurance::all();
        $from = $request->from;
        $to = $request->to;
        $insurance_id = $request->insurance_id;
        $exported = $request->exported;

        if($request-> myInput) {
        //function travelled date
        $travelleddate = InsuranceEnrollment::where('status', '=', 2)
            ->where("insurance_id", $insurance_id)
            ->whereBetween('depart_date', [$from, $to])
            ->orderBy('depart_date', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(10);
        } 
       else {
        //function issued date
        $issueddate = InsuranceEnrollment::where('status', '=', 2)
            ->where("insurance_id", $insurance_id)
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(10);
        }

        $items = array(
            'items' => $travelleddate,
            'items' => $issueddate,
            'insurances' => $insurances,
            'insurance_id' => $insurance_id,
            'exported' => $exported,
            'from' => $from,
            'to' => $to,
        );

        return view('admin.insurance.sales.home')->with($items);
    }
```

Comment: this code works without any error? why are you using `>`  operator with `string` and `undefined constant`?

Comment: it didnt work after all. Should I request the id of the view at the controller? @BanujanBalendrakumar

Comment: `if(request> "travel")` explain this

Comment: if($request->myInput) , I think this way. Means when the user click the selection with id = myInput, it will go inside the if statement

Answer (score 0):

I think this piece of code may be edited to achieve what you so much long, please mind my comments, but the basic idea is to use the value on the element "select" which is called "insurance_id" to determine an action to follow depending on the value:

```
    $insurance_id = $request->insurance_id; //HERE is where we determine if we are going to use travelled or Issued, since the "name" attribute of the "select" element is "insurance_id"
    $exported = $request->exported;

    if($insurance_id == "Travelled") { //now our conditional should reflect this
    //function travelled date
    $travelleddate = InsuranceEnrollment::where('status', '=', 2)
        ->where("insurance_id", $insurance_id)
        ->whereBetween('depart_date', [$from, $to])
        ->orderBy('depart_date', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(10);
    } 
   elseif($insurance_id == "Issued") { //and this one too, unless a simple else may do here.
    //function issued date
    $issueddate = InsuranceEnrollment::where('status', '=', 2)
        ->where("insurance_id", $insurance_id)
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(10);
    }
```